# Sed hex replace problem

Tags: sed

I created 1 byte NULL file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=file.dd bs=1 count=1` for testing purposes. I got a weird result with the following test:

```
dd if=file.dd | 
  sed 's/\x5e/X/' | 
  xxd
```

```
00000000: 5800              X.
```

How did `sed` get `x5E` from a NULL data stream?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work with any other hex code either (I tried a few)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html -- it's apparently something called a sed escape sequence. `5e` is hex for `^` which sed interprets as "start of line"

Comment: I understand that it shouldn't happen because dd is streaming 16 NULL bytes exactly. From where did sed get this '^'?

Comment: Hex `5e` is the ASCII/Unicode code for the character `^`. @barrycarter is saying that the line is equivalent to `sed 's/^/X/'`. As `^` has a special meaning (start of line), it is matching.

Comment: That's not `NULL` (a string), it's `NUL` (a character). Per POSIX: sed is a text processing tool and so is only expected to work on text files. Text files cannot contain NUL characters (at lest partially because many text processing tools are written in C where NUL is the string termination character and so a string variable can't hold a NUL in the middle of it). So, trying to use sed on a file that contains NULs is undefined behavior per POSIX and so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` regular expression special character is a zero-width match for
"beginning of the line" and there is an implicit line at the beginning
of the input. Therefore, any input whatever is considered as consisting of at least
one line, and `sed` (or most any regular expression tool) will treat
it as such:

```
$ printf "\0\0\0" | od -c
0000000   \0  \0  \0
0000003
$ printf "\0\0\0" | sed 's/^/Y/' | od -c
0000000    Y  \0  \0  \0  \n
0000005
$ printf "\0\0\0" | perl -ple 's/^/Y/' | od -c
0000000    Y  \0  \0  \0  \n
0000005
```

GNU `sed` has [the additional complication](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html) of treating `\x5e` the same as `^`:

```
$ printf "\0\0\0" | gsed 's/^/Y/' | od -c
0000000    Y  \0  \0  \0
0000004
$ printf "\0\0\0" | gsed 's/\x5e/Y/' | od -c
0000000    Y  \0  \0  \0
0000004
```

To match a literal `^` some other form must be used that does not treat
`^` or `\x5e` as special:

```
$ printf "\0\x5e\0" | gsed 's/[=\x5e]/Y/' | od -c
0000000   \0   Y  \0
0000003
$ printf "\0\x5e\0" | perl -pe 's/\x5e/Y/' | od -c
0000000   \0   Y  \0
0000003
```